# Opensaml Assertion Signature validation failed for decrypted Assertion

Tags: java, encryption, saml, opensaml

I have decrypted a SAML assertion using Opensaml. Although decryption happens without a error, when I tried to validate the Signature of that Assertion it fails with the error

> "org.apache.xml.security.signature.MissingResourceFailureException: The Reference for URI #eimakmeiiebhiefoopoogamnnbibdpkfloophhdd has no XMLSignatureInput"

(For the same configuration if I didn't use encryption, signature validation happens fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that this is an issue with the Decrypter. Problem was decrypted Assertion wasn't properly rooted. By calling **setRootInNewDocument(true)** of the **Decrypter** before
the decryption, you can have properly rooted Assertion. So Signature validation will succeed.

Comment: I did that too but still I am facing same issue. Can you please share your code?

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/agents/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/agent/saml/SAML2SSOManager.java#L751